# Java initializing array of strings

Tags: java

I was doing a Java syntax test and I observed that

```
String[] sA = new String[1]{"aaa"};
```

Is not valid syntax, while:

```
String[] sA = new String[]{"aaa"};
```

Is valid syntax.

Why is this so?
Aren't the two declarations equivalent?

Comment: You should not specify size of array while initializing it using `{}`

Comment: Why has my question been downvoted?

Comment: probably because its a dupe.. People think that you haven't done sufficient research. I personally don't consider this as a bad question :)

Comment: No they're not equivalent, and it is so because that's how the Java Language was defined (see the Java Language Specification).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first syntax is not valid because you are declaring the size of the array twice:

- once explicitly
- another time because the array of strings between { and } has size 1

Doing the same thing twice can introduce potential errors so the java designers decided to permit only the second approach.

Answer (score 5):

Because you can not define dimension expressions when an array initializer is provided.

That means that you can either specify the dimension or the array initializer (i.e. the values). You can't specify both at the same time.

Your second initalization is the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

Declaring an array variable, creating an array, and assigning the reference of the array to the variable can be combined in one statement, as shown below:

```
dataType[] arrayRefVar = new dataType[arraySize];
```

Alternatively you can create arrays as follows:

```
dataType[] arrayRefVar = {value0, value1, ..., valuek};
```

As others have mentioned "you can not define dimension expressions when an array initializer is provided." i.e. you can't do something like this :

```
String[] sA = new String[1]{"aaa"};
```

Moreover,  while declaring a variable, use:

```
String names[] = {"x","y","z"};
```

However, post declaration, if you want to assign an instance of an Array:

```
names = new String[] {"a","b","c"};
```

the declaration syntax is just a syntactic sugar and it is not applicable anymore when assigning values to variables because when values are assigned you need to create an instance properly.